# Checks not running on every file (when running -a) even though they are parsed

Tags: pre-commit.com

### Summary of the problem

I've setup a repository with the checks I developed, designed to be used exclusively in an another repository.
The problem I've been facing is that when I run `pre-commit run -a -v` the checks don't go through every file, and time to time they even change!

### A little more details

- I've run the [identity][1] check and it prints every file in the repo, meaning the files are read by pre-commit (per my understanding)
- When I execute `pre-commit run` the file in staging are correctly parsed

##### Why do i think that the checks don't run on every file?

- I always print something to the standard output for every check, and when I run it verbosely it only prints 5 to 7 lines, meaning it checked only those.
- If I try and edit a file (breaking a check) whose not on the short list, the check still passes through

#### Some code

The structure of the folder containing the files to be checked

```
./
    articles/
             some_name/
                       file.md
                       file.png
                       and_so_on.jpeg
    team/
         some_other_name/
                       file.md
                       propic.jpg
```

Summary of the `.pre-commit-hooks.yaml`

```yaml
-   id: team-check-name
    name: blabla
    description: blabla
    entry: team-checkname
    files: 'team/.*/'
    types: [markdown]
    language: python

-   id: article-check-name
    name: blabla
    description: blabla
    entry: article-checkname
    files: 'articles/.*/'
    types: [markdown]
    language: python
```

Essentially the checks supposed to run on `articles/.*/` start with `article-` and they all have this property: `files: 'articles/.*/'`.
Similarly every check supposed to run on `team/.*/` starts with `team-` and they all have `files: 'team/.*/'`

Summary of the `.pre-commit-config.yaml`

```yaml
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/repourl
    rev: commit_hash
    hooks:
    -   id: team-check-name
    -   id: article-check-name
```

But as you can see, I don't override any settings so it shouldn't interfere

Comment: please edit the relevant parts into the actual question -- external links aren't helpful since code changes over time and repositories get deleted

Comment: Yep, you're completely right, edited just now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the hook tools you've written are incorrect -- they only process `sys.argv[1]` rather than [positional arguments](https://pre-commit.com/#arguments-pattern-in-hooks)

your code uses a lot of global variables so it's not a straightforward refactor -- typically you'd either use `argparse` to collect `nargs='*'` or loop over `sys.argv[1:]` (if you don't have any options)

as to why this is the convention -- it's very wasteful to start a linter process over and over to lint a single file (often times executable startup cost *dwarfs* the actual linting / formatting process)

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: Oh, got it thanks! Basically i was checking the first file of every "batch". That makes sense. Sadly i missed that part in the documentation, would've wasted a lot less time. Thanks again :)